# how to parse a page including embedded page/ iframe?

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I want to parse a streaming website in PHP to find the streaming links and codes.

The streaming page ie index.htm looks like

```
<html>
<iframe> something something src= xyz.aspx?id=abc <iframe>
<\html>
```

When I parse the main page I can see those codes..but I need to parse the code of xyz.asx?id....
If I parse that page directly it doesnt show the streaming codes...
The main page and the iframe page somehow connected...
Is there any way to parse both at the same time..perhaps with referring or something..so the the second page thinks as if it is loaded on the stream page.
Any clue? Curl?

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you are only searching for a couple codes, you might want to write a regex (GASP! I KNOW, REGEX + HTML = BAD, hear me out). I'd find a regex that captures all `<iframe>` tags. Then parse those for the `src` attribute, and then get the information that you need.

Edit: I don't think I understood your question entirely, you also want to embed the iframe'd page as if it were viewed in a browser?

If so, read on!

Ok, now that you have the `src` attribute of the `<iframe>`, just download the linked page (I'm a little rusty with PHP, I'm sure you can find one of the *thousands* of functions that would work) and `str_replace()` the `<iframe>` tag with the downloaded code

Comment: What i am aiming on is to parse the iframe page as if it was loaded on a browser. If i parse that link directly i get some random codes. But when i load the first page in the browser and view source for the embeded iframe i can see all the codes i need. So i need to parse the whole thing at the same time to find my code from deep.

Comment: Found the solution. I had to curl the iframe src with referral  of hosting site. It gives me the codes I need. Thanks for support.